# React native Redirect authentication api

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth, react-native

As i am new to react native stuck at one point.

I am developing an app in which i am using wordpress as a backend to store the new users data.

To Create a new user i need authentication as i am using [wp rest api](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/) plugin to create user.

For authentication i have used [Oauth Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) plugin in wordpress admin.

Now issue is as per the [Oauth documentation](https://wp-oauth.com/knowledge-base/using-authorization-code/) i need to get the authentication code in my app.

> So want to know how to **redirect_uri** to our react-native app so that i can get authorization code in app?

Answer (score 1):

To get authorization code in react-native app, You need to set the custom Url scheme.

twitter has well documented guide to create it.

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes

After creating the Url scheme. You need to set the redirect_uri as explained  [here](https://wp-oauth.com/kb/setting-up-single-sign-on/) in wp-oauth server's docs Step 2 and replace the created custom url of your app in redirect_uri.

This will redirect you to your app when oauth server's callback with the access token that you can use in your react-native application.